# Click Android Button,But nothing happen?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Click on the Button, But nothing happen, Why? 
I traversal all controls First， if it's Button control, then `setsetOnClickListener`.

**MainActivity class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout MainLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    for (int i = 0; i < MainLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = MainLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof Button)
        {
            Button button = (Button) v;
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.ButtonGetContent:
            EditText txtContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_Name);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,txtContent.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        default:
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to inflate the layout that's already inflated?

Comment: You're right,it works now,thanks

Comment: What works? My answer?

Comment: Yes,you answer is right, I shouldn't inflate the layout twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
setContentView(MainLayout);
```

If you want to find the buttons that are actually part of that view

Answer (score -1):

You have to add v.Button.setOnclickListner(this);

Comment: Your edit didn't help. That's exactly what the code does